# How to find an IP in overlapping ranges of IPs?

Tags: algorithms, intervals

I have a large number (millions) of IP ranges which might overlap. An IP range should contain the start IP, stop IP and an range id. How can I efficiently find which ranges contain a given IP?

I could iterate over all the ranges and check for every range if it contains the IP, but I'm looking for a complexity better than O(n).

Comment: Convert your IP address into an integer: etc: 192.168.0.1 -> 192168000001. Then use an interval tree to find all ranges that intersect with a given number.

Answer (score 3):

Store your IP address as an integer or long depending on whether it is 32 or 64 bit. Then put the ranges into an [interval tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) or similar data structure that will allow you to find all ranges that intersect with a given range or point (in this case the IP address you want to check against). This will have a query time of O(lg N) after a preprocessing time of O(N lgN). For K queries this is thus O((N+K)*lg N) which should be fast enough.